# Можно ли удалить старые версии windows software development kit?

Tags: windows

Можно ли удалить старые версии windows software development kit?

[image: windows software development kit]

Просто каждая версия занимает 2 гигабайта.
Я спрашиваю, потому что странно, почему они сами не удалились при загрузке новой версии, значит наверное они нужны? Или их всё же можно удалить?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте об этом [тут](https://meshok-sovetov.ru/windows-software-development-kit-mozhno-li-udalyat/), [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/remove-windows-app-sdk-versions) и ещё [тут](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/219230957). Вот кусок статьи, который, по-моему, подходит Вам больше всего:

## Можно ли удалить данную программу?

> Места на диске она занимает очень мало, но при этом является программой от *Майкрософт* (значит точно безопасна). В процессах не висит, в автозагрузке ее тоже не должно быть.
> Тем не менее, если вы хотите удалить программу — лучше сначала сделать точку восстановления:
> Зажимаете <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, пишите команду:
>
> [image: Команда]
>
> Команда откроет окошко **Свойства системы**.
> Нажимаете **ОК**.
> У вас откроется окно **Свойства системы**, здесь активируете вкладку **Защита системы**, где выбираете **Системный диск** и нажимаете **Создать**:
>
> [image: Окошко]
>
> У меня кнопка неактивна, просто восстановление отключено. Но у вас — должна быть активна, в противном случае нажмите **Настроить** и включите восстановление.
> Точку советую называть на понятном языке, например до удаления *Windows SDK AddOn*.
> Теперь можете смело удалять *Windows SDK AddOn*, и даже другие программы, в том числе и системные. А если будут проблемы — при помощи точки восстановитесь до прежнего состояния ПК.
> Лично я советую удалять только при наличии точки восстановления! Это важно!